# Subtracting two numbers in a list and subtracting the difference to another number adjacent to the previous numbers before

Tags: python

I have a list such as:

```
num = 296
lst = [256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

subtract num by the first element in the list;

```
296 -256 = 40
```

the difference is 40, so how do I subtract the difference (40) to 128?

Also doing the same thing till the whole list has been subtracted

```
-> 296 -256 = 40 , 40 - 128 = -88 , -88 - 64 = -152...
```

and so on

Comment: `num - sum(lst)`?

Comment: Do you want an array or number at the end

Comment: an array at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import reduce

num = 296
lst = [256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]

lst.insert(1,num)

print(reduce(lambda a,b : a-b,lst)) 
# -295

# test

(((((((((256-296)-128)-64)-32)-16)-8)-4)-2)-1)
# -295
```